# Why cant my website hosted on XAMP has a Database error on localhost?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

Hey so this morning suddenly I got a "Error establishing a database connection" error:
[Error on the localhost website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hil7.png)

On the windows event viewer, I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D5lu.png)

Comment: Xampp https://i.imgur.com/e0hrbvB.png

Comment: I cant even access: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php!!